# Store images for Chrome Packaged App

Tags: google-chrome-app

I am developing a chrome packaged app , where i have to download  and store Gigabytes  of images into a local persistent storage. Is there any way to do it ? I am using IndexedDB to save other data .

Comment: Do you need those files to be user-accessible outside the app?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, chrome apps are not designed to store gigabytes of data on your hard drive. Think of chromebooks users whose hard drive is only 16Gb.

But if you still want to store images inside your app, local filesystem is your choice. As for me, I made a simple web component `<img is="external-image">`, which makes this:

1. Creates URL hash with md5/sha1
2. Checks whether this file has already been downloaded to local filesystem
3. If it was already downloaded, get this FileEntry's URL with FileEntry.toURL()
4. Otherwise fetch this file with XHR with responseType = 'blob' and save this blob into local filesystem. Respond with `URL.createObjectURL(blob);`.

Sample implementation is [here](https://github.com/1999/vkoffline/blob/master/src/js/utils.js#L535). Btw `detachedCallback` helps with managing created URIs perfectly - you can revoke them in this callback thus helping your app to cleanup memory.